# Statements after Switch being skipped

Tags: c#, debugging, switch-statement, control-flow

I may be having a senior moment here (*at 22 years old*), but I can't figure out why C# is skipping a statement I have included after a `switch`. The code goes as follows:

```
switch (shape)
{
    case ToolShape.BasicTool:
        EditTool = (LastTool.ToolType == ToolShape.BasicTool)
            ? new BasicTool((BasicTool)LastTool)
            : new BasicTool(ToolNumber, BasicToolType.TypeA,
                "Tool " + ToolNumber, "", 1.0, 60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0);
        break;

    case ToolShape.AdvancedTool:
        EditTool = (LastTool.ToolType == ToolShape.AdvancedTool)
            ? new AdvancedTool((AdvancedTool)LastTool)
            : new AdvancedTool(AdvancedTool, "Tool " + ToolNumber, "", 1.0, 10.0, 2.0, 
                AdvancedTool.Light, AdvancedTool.Round);
        break;

    case ToolShape.SpecialTool:
        EditTool = (LastTool.ToolType == ToolShape.SpecialTool)
            ? new SpecialTool((SpecialTool)LastTool)
            : new SpecialTool(SpecialTool, "Tool " + ToolNumber, "", 
                1.0, 1.0, 90.0);
        break;
}

// We never seem to reach anything below here ----------------
LoadToolToForm(EditTool);
```

It's never hitting that `LoadToolToForm(EditTool)` statement. Or a `MessageBox.Show("...")` I stuck in there, for debugging purposes. Removing the `switch` works as expected. Putting even a really small switch in there with a single case causes it to exit prematurely again, though.

Is this known behavior? Is there a situation in which `breaking` from a switch statement causes the function to exit (without ever invoking the return keyword).

Comment: This is not something I have seen before, and I use a lot of switches.  Try stepping through each in the debugger.  If that does not find the issue for you then please put up the complete method.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the switch statement and see what happens. You'll find out an exception was thrown.

Comment: Are there any errors occurring during the EdiTool process?

Comment: When debugging, there are no obvious errors. It just selects the output for EditTool (and the Immediate window seems to confirm that it's working) and then cuts right back to user input mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure the code is never passing the switch statement, there is only one other possibility:

There is an exception being thrown in the switch statement, and it is being caught somewhere higher up so the program just continues.

One thing you could try to verify this suggestion would be wrapping your switch in a temporary `try{}catch{}` block and showing a MessageBox on Exception, or use lots of breakpoints.

Comment: I'll look into it. I don't *think* I have any Exception-swallowing code in there... but the last developer might have put some in.

Comment: Enclose the switch statement with try and catch blocks and catch the exception. Then see the line of code in which exception has been thrown (during debug you can see the line) and then debug on that line. I had the same problem yesterday and solved it this way.

Comment: @Nick Yep, looks like there's an exception. I wonder why it was getting swallowed. Time to delve in deeper. But at least I know what was causing the behavior, and I'm back in territory I recognize.

Comment: @Caesay I'll give you the Accepted Answer when SO lets me (say, 7 minutes).